# How to output messages to the Eclipse console when developing for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I print messages (like a flag) to the Eclipse console (or log) when developing and debugging an Android app

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Rather than trying to output to the console, `Log` will output to LogCat which you can find in Eclipse by going to: *Window->Show View->Other…->Android->LogCat*

Have a look at the [reference for `Log`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

The benefits of using LogCat are that you can print different colours depending on your log type, e.g.: `Log.d` prints blue, `Log.e` prints orange. Also you can filter by ***log tag***, ***log message***, ***process id*** and/or by ***application name***. This is really useful when you just want to see your app's logs and keep the other system stuff separate.

Comment: my, my, how simple it can be....  these little tidbits help those of us that are NEW to these platforms. Thanks m6tt!   FYI: there is a Filter option here that helps VERY MUCH~

Answer (score 48):

```
Log.v("blah", "blah blah");
```

You need to add the android Log view in eclipse to see them. There are also other methods depending on the severity of the message (error, verbose, warning, etc..).

Comment: +1 How about doing this in library? I have tried to but it doesn't show anything on logcat.

Answer (score 29):

`System.out.println()` also outputs to LogCat. The benefit of using good old `System.out.println()` is that you can print an object like `System.out.println(object)` to the console if you need to check if a variable is initialized or not.

`Log.d`, `Log.v`, `Log.w` etc methods only allow you to print strings to the console and not objects. To circumvent this (if you desire), you must use `String.format`.

Comment: Or, for object instances, you can always use `toString()`. This is what `System.out.println(Object)` does internally. If the `toString()` method of `Object` itself is used (e.g. for array types) then you may not get useful output.

Comment: saves me the typing. I always love when Objects take care of itself. ;
)

Comment: It doesn't dump the object, it prints the same as `Log`.

Comment: ..and it still saves me the creation of a string constant for Log.whatever, and typing it every time I want something in the console, and formatting the object to the string.

Comment: If your object is null, toString() will obviously throw a NPE. You should never call toString() on an object in a log statement but rather use a logging library that will do these checks if you just pass in an object.

Answer (score 15):

I use Log.d method also please import `import android.util.Log;`

```
Log.d("TAG", "Message");
```

But please keep in mind that, when you want to see the debug messages then don't use Run As
rather use **"Debug As"** then select Android Application. Otherwise you'll not see the debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

i use below log format for print my content in logCat

```
Log.e("Msg","What you have to print");
```

Comment: The first parameter is the [tag, not the message](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).