# In sqlite database I insert the image and retrieve from it . But my image is not displaying in the list

Tags: android

create table in database :-

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

```
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ITEMNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ITEMPRICE + " TEXT," + KEY_ITEMQUANTITY + " TEXT," + KEY_ITEMIMAGE + " TEXT" + ")";


    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);


}
```

method of insert data in databasehandler class :

public void insertData(String itemname, String itemprice, String itemimage)throws SQLiteException{

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_ITEMNAME, itemname);
    values.put(KEY_ITEMPRICE, itemprice);
    values.put(KEY_ITEMIMAGE, itemimage);

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    db.close();

}
```

data insert into the database :-

dbh.insertData(jsonObj.getString("DishName"),jsonObj.getString("Rate"),
jsonObj.getString("Image"));

retrieve the data from the database and add in the model class :-

Cursor c = dbh.getSingledData(id);

```
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {


        int id = c.getInt(0);
        ItemName = c.getString(1);

        ItemPrice = c.getString(2);

        ItemImage = c.getString(4);


        for (int i = 0; i < ItemName.length(); i++) {
            PojoCart pojoCart = new PojoCart();

            pojoCart.setmItemName(ItemName);
            pojoCart.setmItemPrice(ItemPrice);
            pojoCart.setmItemImage(ItemImage);


            mCartList.add(pojoCart);
```

my Adapter class is :-
`PojoCart pojoCart = (PojoCart) getItem(position);
        viewHolder.mTvItemName.setText(pojoCart.getmItemName());
        viewHolder.mTvItemPrice.setText(pojoCart.getmItemPrice());
        try {
            URL url = new URL(pojoCart.getmItemImage());
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            viewHolder.mImgItem.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();`
}

```
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if the image inserting and retrieving of image is returning correct values?

Comment: how can i check this ??

Comment: You either put breakpoint or log the error. Log can be either Log.d or Log.e  for more reference from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007644/how-to-output-messages-to-the-eclipse-console-when-developing-for-android   e.g `Log.v(IMAGE VALUE, "ImageValue= " + ItemImage);` put in your forloop in retrieving of image file/section

Comment: yes ! it is returning correct values ! but image is not displaying in the list ! its returning in this form [B@37d34ce7 !

Comment: is this image URL or just the name of the image stored in your application?

Comment: it is just the name of the image stored in my app !

Comment: Then dont store them in an byte array. Store them as a normal string in SQLite and then try.

Comment: `URL url = new URL(ItemImage);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);` Dont covert anything. Just store string in ur database. And then use this in ur retirve forloop.

Comment: i do this ! but no image is showing ! and i surrounded this code with the try catch block ! because it gives compile time error !

Comment: Did you remove the converting of imageURL to bytes? and just storing imageUrl as it is?

Comment: yes ! i storing image url as it is ! but when convert into bitmap ! its changed its form like [B@27b82bb3

Comment: So it is not working is it? Can you update existing code?. so can i check if you are doing it correctly or not

Comment: i updated code ! please check it ! and tell me the solution !

Comment: Looks good. Do you have the stack trace of the catch? is it throwing anything? Secondly can you just re-format your code, its not that readable!

Comment: the stack trace of the catch is E/exception: null